# Math::BigInt error: Can't locate object method "bmuladd"

Tags: perl, bigint

I'm trying to do an arithmetic operation involving big numbers using `Math::BigInt`.

My intention is to multiply the variable `k` by `4` and then subtract `1`. Below is my Perl file attempt MWE:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::BigInt;

my $k = '174224571863520493293247799005065324265473'; 
my $int = $k->bmuladd(4,-1);
printf ($int);
```

I get the following error message:

```
Can't locate object method "bmuladd" via package "2" (perhaps you forgot to load "2"?) at pv5.pl line 7.
```

Reading https://perldoc.perl.org/Math::BigInt#Arithmetic-methods, I could not understand something that helped solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a `Math::BigInt` object using `new` before you can use methods such as `bmuladd`.  Refer to the [SYNOPSIS](https://perldoc.perl.org/Math::BigInt#SYNOPSIS) section of the doc:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::BigInt;

my $k = '174224571863520493293247799005065324265473'; 
my $x = Math::BigInt->new($k);
my $int = $x->bmuladd(4,-1);
print "$int\n";
```

Prints:

```
696898287454081973172991196020261297061891
```

Comment: And once you are working with a blessed `Math::BigInt` object, all the arithmetic operators are overloaded to do what you mean, and you can just say `$int = $x * 4 - 1`.